# How do I mount my NTFS hard drive partition?

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ntfs

My computer's internal hard drive has an intermediate partition called 'Storage' which can be accessed from either Windows or Ubuntu. It is an NTFS partition but when I try to mount it in Ubuntu as root using:

```
sudo /usr/bin/udisks --mount /dev/sda3
```

I get the following error message:

```
Mount failed: Error mounting: mount exited with exit code 1: helper failed with:
mount: unknown filesystem type 'ntfs-3g'
```

Please note that I only have a very basic understanding of Ubuntu so if anyone could give me step by step instructions to fix this it would be very much appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo mount -t ntfs /dev/sdXn /path/to/dir`

/dev/sdXn should be the partition, e.g. /dev/sda2 (you can find it in Disk Utility if you don't know it).

/path/to/dir can be any existing empty directory where you want to mount the partition. Typically e.g. /media/ntfs.

If that returns an error about lack of `ntfs-3g`, check that you have the package of that name installed.

Comment: I tried that and it gave a message saying that it mounted as a read only drive. It isn't showing up under devices in the file browser and when I attempt to open the directory it created (/media/Storage) I get an error message saying I do not have permissions to view the contents of 'Storage'.

Comment: @Kyle: you can try viewing it from the root user. if that works, you can try mounting with a different umask to allow non-owners to access the directory too